# Existence of a zero of a function $f:(0;1) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, roots

Let $f:(0;1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x):=-\ln(1-x)-cx$ for some $c>1$.

How does one show the existence of a zero $0 < a < 1$, $f(a)=0$? I can't work out a development for the intermediate value theorem or the fixpoint theorem (Banach)...

Comment: Hint: Intermediate Value Theorem. Show that for some $x$, $f(x)>0$ and for some $y$, $f(y)<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f $ is differentiable at $ (0,1)$ and

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-c=\frac{cx+1-c}{1-x}$$

So,

$$\forall x\in (0,1-\frac 1c)\; f'(x)<0$$

$$\implies f(1-\frac 1c)-f(0)=(1-\frac 1c)f'(y)<0$$
By MVT.

On the other side,
$$(\forall n\ge 0)\;\;f(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\le 0$$
$$\implies \lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)\le 0$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=+\infty$$

thus, apply IVT at $ [1-\frac 1c,1-\frac{1}{2^n}]$.

Comment: IVT = Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: MVT = ??? (as a non-native english speaker, I don't know many theorem abbreviations) ;)

Comment: @PhilippeKnecht Medium Value Theorem $f(a)-f(b)=(a-b)f'(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Study the variation of $f$ on $\left]0;1\right[$ and show there exists $x_0$ such as $f\left(x_0\right)<0$.
Then note that
$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1}f\left(x\right)=+\infty
$$

Comment: Looking at the derivative, I get that $\frac{c-1}{c}$ is a global minimum of my function. Does this bring me any further?